Where to Add SEO Metadata in Next.js with App Router Instead of Page Router
I have recently migrated from using page router to app router in Next.js, and accordingly shifted from _app.tsx to layout.tsx. Here are the snippets showing the old setup using page router (①) and the new setup with app router (②).
When using the page router, I had implemented SEO metadata such as Twitter, Facebook, and OpenGraph settings in _app.tsx. How should I adapt this to work with the app router setup? Where do I place the DefaultSeo component or equivalent SEO metadata in the new structure?
①
import { ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import { DefaultSeo, DefaultSeoProps } from "next-seo";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { Providers } from "@/components/providers/providers";
import "@/i18n";
import { FB_PIXEL_ID } from "@/lib/fbmeta/metaPixel";

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

const defaultSeo: DefaultSeoProps = {
  title: "test",
  defaultTitle: "test",
  description: "test",
  openGraph: {
    type: "website",
    url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL,
    images: [
      {
        url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/ogp.png`,
        width: 1200,
        height: 630,
        alt: "test",
      },
    ],
  },
  twitter: {
    handle: "****",
    site: "*****",
  },
  facebook: {
    appId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID}`,
  },
};

function App({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <DefaultSeo {...defaultSeo} />
        <title>{defaultSeo.title}</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicons/favicon.png" />
        <noscript>
          <img
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            src={`https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=${FB_PIXEL_ID}&ev=PageView&noscript=1`}
          />
        </noscript>
      </Head>
      <Providers>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Providers>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

②
import { Metadata } from "next";
import { Providers } from "@/components/providers/providers";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "test",
  description: "test",
};

type Props = Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>;

export default function RootLayout(props: Props) {
  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <Providers>{props.children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



Where do I place the DefaultSeo component or equivalent SEO metadata in the new structure?

You will not use a component but plain JavaScript object/function in the export const metadata = {} or export function generateMetadata() {} of your root layout, e.g. at /app/layout.tsx
Check out the official docs about it https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#ordering
